# In template reactive context, how can I retrieve thrown error from collection?

Tags: meteor

I have the following code:

```
GetPublication = new Meteor.Collection 'get-publication'

Meteor.autorun ->
  Meteor.subscribe 'get-publication', Session.get 'currentPublicationId', {
    onReady: console.log "ready"
    onError: (error) -> console.error "error", error
  }

Template.publication.publication = ->
  # How to know here what was an error thrown in subscription?
  JSON.stringify GetPublication.findOne()
```

I have a custom collection:

```
Meteor.publish 'get-publication', (publicationId) ->
  self = this
  self.ready()
  self.error new Meteor.Error 500, "Test"
```

I would like to output the message in the template with the content thrown in the subscription, instead of the (empty) publication collection result.

Furthermore, why `onReady` and `onError` handlers are not called?

Comment: Why did you call your collection "get-publication"? Isn't it a collection of publications? Wouldn't "publications" be a better name?

Comment: No, it is not a collection of publications. Maybe I am doing it wrong, but the idea is that I have a dummy collection which pushes to the client various stages of preparing the publication. If I would use a method, I can just return the final result. I want to be sending updates/progress messages. And I also want that I can send an error if there is some error in between. At the end, the last collection content is that the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the result of `console.log("ready")` to `onReady`. The correct syntax is:

```
onReady: -> console.log "ready"
```

If you want to print the error you're given, I imagine you'd want to store what you get from the error callback in a variable (such as `Session`) and then print that in the template. Something like this:

```
Meteor.autorun ->
  Meteor.subscribe 'get-publication', Session.get 'currentPublicationId', {
    onReady: -> console.log "ready"
    onError: (error) -> Session.set "get-publication-error", error
  }

Template.publication.publicationError = ->
  JSON.stringify(Session.get "get-publication-error")
```

Comment: Grr, `onError` still does not seem to be called.

Comment: Ah, I found an error. There is comma after `Session.get 'currentPublicationId'` so object with callbacks is passed to `Session.get`.

Comment: Still, `error` does not seem to contain parameters I pass to `new Meteor.Error`. :-(